# GitLab CI Pipeline Incorrectly Triggers on All Branches Despite Specific Workflow Rules

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've set up a GitLab CI configuration intended to trigger pipelines only on the develop and main branches when the commit message starts with "deploy" and the event is a push. Despite this, the pipeline is unexpectedly executing on push events to any branch, including ones not specified in the configuration, such as feature/partially_fill. Here's my current .gitlab-ci.yml setup:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop" && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^deploy.*/ && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main" && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^deploy.*/ && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
    
include:
  - local: '/.gitlab-ci-develop.yml'
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"'
        when: always

  - local: '/.gitlab-ci-main.yml'
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"'
        when: always
```

The intention is clear: pipelines should only run on develop and main branches under specific conditions. However, it's not behaving as expected.

Questions:

1. Why is the GitLab CI pipeline being triggered on branches other than develop and main, despite the explicit conditions set in the workflow rules?
2. Is there a mistake in my configuration that's causing the CI pipeline to ignore the specified branch conditions?
3. How can I adjust my GitLab CI configuration to ensure that pipelines only run on develop and main branches when the commit message starts with "deploy" and the source is a push event?

Any insights or suggestions to correct this behavior would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: your workflow rules look fine and I have tested these workflow rules on a sample project https://gitlab.com/cdoyle27/ci-examples and when I run a commit on main it doesnt trigger, if i deploy a commit on main starting with deploy it triggers, if i deploy a feature branch and commit it doesnt trigger.

Comment: thanks for your comment the problem was in using include i don't know what was the problem but it was fixed by using the trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the using the Include function don't know why but it was fixed using the following CI:

```
stages:
  - trigger-services

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop" && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^deploy.*/
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main" && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^deploy.*/

develop:
  stage: trigger-services
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"
  trigger:
    include: '/.gitlab-ci-develop.yml'
    strategy: depend

production:
  stage: trigger-services
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
  trigger:
    include: '/.gitlab-ci-production.yml'
    strategy: depend
```